# There is a way to comment blade on vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Sorry for asking the newbie things. Is there a way to comment one line including HTML + blade syntax on vscode? Regularly, I use `ctrl + /` for comment, but doesn't seem that's work on blade syntax. example:

```
<td class="align-middle" align="center"><img height='200' src="/storage/photos/{{$member->before}}"+ class='css-class' alt='Not Found'></img></td>
```

Thanks before.

Comment: what is blade syntax?

Comment: PHP template on laravel

Comment: see in the language definition of the extension you use there is a definition for line and block comment, if not create an issue at the repo

Answer (score 0):

Install Laravel Blade Snippets extension for VSCode
then you can comment in blade file by ctrl + /

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJPac.png)